# Fungi growing in pH 1 FeCl₃ solution

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I have a FeCl<sub>3</sub> tank that I use to dip spruce wood in. After 2–3 weeks a fungus appears in the tank and it keeps growing with time. The fungus has a white colour and is spread throughout the whole tank. It looks like mainly on the surface but its everywhere in the fluid. 
The FeCl<sub>3</sub> solution has pH 1 and that doesn't change with time. 
Can anybody tell me what it might be? What's the best way to make sure it doesn't occur anymore?
[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Comment: I would suspect an iron oxidizing extremophile bacteria not a fungi. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5023253/